# Typeclass Derivation of Coproduct?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the following from the well-written [shapeless-guide](http://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/):

```
package net

import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless._

sealed trait JsonValue
case class JsonObject(fields: List[(String, JsonValue)]) extends JsonValue
case class JsonArray(items: List[JsonValue])             extends JsonValue
case class JsonString(value: String)                     extends JsonValue
case class JsonNumber(value: Double)                     extends JsonValue
case class JsonBoolean(value: Boolean)                   extends JsonValue
case object JsonNull                                     extends JsonValue
```

The text demonstrates how to derive a `JsonEncoder` type-class instance for the above data structure:

```
trait JsonEncoder[A] {
  def encode(value: A): JsonValue
}
object JsonEncoder {

  def apply[A](implicit ev: JsonEncoder[A]): JsonEncoder[A] =
    ev

  def instance[A](f: A => JsonValue): JsonEncoder[A] =
    new JsonEncoder[A] {
      override def encode(x: A): JsonValue = f(x)
    }

  implicit val doubleEncoder: JsonEncoder[Double] =
    instance[Double](JsonNumber)

  // omitted other instances (String, Boolean, etc.)

  trait JsonObjectEncoder[A] extends JsonEncoder[A] {
    def encode(value: A): JsonObject
  }

  def createObjectEncoder[A](fn: A => JsonObject): JsonObjectEncoder[A] =
    new JsonObjectEncoder[A] {
      override def encode(value: A): JsonObject = fn(value)
    }

  implicit val hnilEncoder: JsonObjectEncoder[HNil] =
    createObjectEncoder(hnil => JsonObject(Nil))

  implicit def hlistObjectEncoder[K <: Symbol, H, T <: HList](
    implicit
     witness: Witness.Aux[K],
     hEncoder: Lazy[JsonEncoder[H]],
     tEncoder: JsonObjectEncoder[T]
  ): JsonObjectEncoder[FieldType[K, H] :: T] =
    createObjectEncoder { hlist =>
      val fieldName = witness.value.name
      val head      = hEncoder.value.encode(hlist.head)
      val tail      = tEncoder.encode(hlist.tail)
      JsonObject( (fieldName, head) :: tail.fields )
  }

  implicit def genericObjectEncoder[A, H <: HList](
    implicit
    generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, H],
    hEncoder: Lazy[JsonObjectEncoder[H]]
  ): JsonEncoder[A] =
    createObjectEncoder { value =>
      hEncoder.value.encode(  generic.to(value) )
    }
```

I attempted to define the `coproductEncoder`:

```
 implicit val cnilEncoder: JsonObjectEncoder[CNil] =
    createObjectEncoder { cnil => throw new RuntimeException("Inconceivable!") }

  implicit def coproductEncoder[H, T <: Coproduct](
    implicit
    hEncoder: Lazy[JsonObjectEncoder[H]],
    tEncoder: JsonObjectEncoder[T]
  ): JsonEncoder[H :+: T] = createObjectEncoder {
    case Inl(h) => hEncoder.value.encode(h)
    case Inr(t) => tEncoder.encode(t)
  }
```

The above code, after adding my coproduct encoder attempt, compiles, but it fails to derive a coproduct:

```
sealed trait A
case class B(x: Double) extends A

scala> net.JsonEncoder[A]
<console>:13: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: net.JsonEncoder[A]
       net.JsonEncoder[A]
                      ^
```

Can you please give me a hint as to why my `coproductEncoder` is not working?

Answer (score 4):

[Sealed families of case classes](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes) are different from Coproducts in the same way case classes are different from Products. You added both `hlistObjectEncoder` and `genericObjectEncoder` for case classes, logically you need something similar for coproduct. In your code you have added the derivation for Coproducts but you forgot to tell `JsonEncoder` that, if a Coproduct can be derived then a sealed family of case classes which has that Coproduct as generic representation can be derived. You can add this with

```
implicit def genericFamilyEncoder[A, C <: Coproduct](
  implicit
  generic: Generic.Aux[A, C],
  cEncoder: Lazy[JsonObjectEncoder[C]]
): JsonEncoder[A] =
  instance { value =>
    cEncoder.value.encode(  generic.to(value) )
  }
```

note that this doesn't compile directly because your `coproductEncoder` needs a `JsonObjectEncoder` for `H`, that represent each element of the Coproduct that you want to encode, but you only provide `JsonEncoder` for case classes with `genericObjectEncoder`. Consequently, you cannot even derive something like `B :+: CNil`, which is the generic representation of `A`, for instance. The solution could be to either change `genericObjectEncoder` to return a `JsonObjectEncoder` or to change `coproductEncoder` to take in input a `JsonEncoder` for `H`. The two strategies have different results, pick the one it's best for you. I prefer the first solution because I think you want all the elements of a coproduct to have a `JsonObject` encoding but it's up to you. The code with the first solution would be:

```
implicit def genericObjectEncoder[A, H <: HList](
  implicit
  generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, H],
  hEncoder: Lazy[JsonObjectEncoder[H]]
): JsonObjectEncoder[A] =
  createObjectEncoder { value =>
    hEncoder.value.encode(generic.to(value))
  }

implicit val cnilEncoder: JsonObjectEncoder[CNil] =
  createObjectEncoder { cnil => throw new RuntimeException("Inconceivable!") }

implicit def coproductEncoder[H, T <: Coproduct](
  implicit
  hEncoder: Lazy[JsonObjectEncoder[H]],
  tEncoder: JsonObjectEncoder[T]
): JsonObjectEncoder[H :+: T] = createObjectEncoder {
  case Inl(h) => hEncoder.value.encode(h)
  case Inr(t) => tEncoder.encode(t)
}

implicit def genericFamilyEncoder[A, C <: Coproduct](
  implicit
  generic: Generic.Aux[A, C],
  cEncoder: Lazy[JsonObjectEncoder[C]]
): JsonEncoder[A] =
  instance { value =>
    cEncoder.value.encode(  generic.to(value) )
  }
```